# Connect MobileFirst Application with DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Mobilefirst 8.0. I wanted to connect my hybrid application to DB2 database and create table in that and retrieve data from this.  I just came to know after reading some documents that have to use sql adapter. but

1) how to configure and add external dependancies of JDBC driver?

2) Can I do this from my local developer server?
Please any one can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You have several questions there...

> I wanted to connect my hybrid application to DB2 database and create table in that

To create a DB2 database and table in it, you need to install DB2 and create a table in it. This is not related to IBM MobileFirst. Consult the DB2 documentation.

> ...  and retrieve data from this. I just came to know after reading some documents that have to use sql adapter.

In IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 you can create either a Java adapter or a JavaScript adapter, depending on your proficiency and your project requirements.

1. In a Java adapter it is expected that you will create and handle the database connection as is standard in Java programming.

   - Read more about creating Java adapters: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/
   - Read more about SQL in Java adapters: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/java-adapters/java-sql-adapter/

   In JavaScript adapters, MobileFirst Server takes care of many aspects, but you still need to do some minimal configurations, such as providing the database URL, and the username and password for it.

   - Read more about JavaScript adapters: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/
   - Read more about SQL JavaScript adapters: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/js-sql-adapter/
2. About retrieving data and display it, etc, there are plenty of existing questions about this in Stack Overflow. Simply search for some implementation pointers.

> How to configure and add external dependancies of JDBC driver

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 adapters are actually Maven projects. As such dependencies such as database connectors are handled via the Maven dependencies mechanism.

- Learn more about adapters in general: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/
- Learn how to creating adapters and adding dependencies: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/

Since you're using DB2, you need to search the Maven repository for a DB2 connector and add it to your adapter's pom.xml file, then build the adapter to verify that it manages to pull the connector and that there are no compilation errors.

The example SQL adapter provided in the links above defined a connector for a MySQL database in its pom.xml. You can base your adapter on the changes made in that sample adapter.

For example:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.47</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
    <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cu</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.47</version>
</dependency>
```

> Can I do this from my local developer server?

This is not related to the server. It is all done in the adapter.

Comment: so to do this I have to install DB2 first then configure adapter right?

Comment: I am getting this error while invoking SQL adapter.. Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: getAccountTransactions2 in adapter: SampleAdapter
SQL connection creation failed